# How to add click visual state on listpicker to wp8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, listpicker, visualstates

How do I set the click visual state on my listpicker for my wp8 app? I want to change foreground and background on the listpicker

Answer (score 0):

You can change the highlighted visual state  in List Picker and can change the required values.